# NullPointerException при работе с потоками

Tags: java

Не могу понять, что не так в 14 строке (условие вложенного цикла while). Ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> solution.Solution.main(Solution.java:15)

Исходный код:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
    static int a[] = new int [100500];
    static int b[] = new int [100500];
        static java.util.Stack st;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();

                for (int i = n-1; i>=0; i--){
                    while (st.peek() <= a[i]) 
                        st.pop();
                    b[i] = st.peek();
                    st.push(a[i]);                    
                }

                for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
                    System.out.print(b[i]+" "); 
    }
}
```

Comment: А ничего что у вас в обоих циклах используется i ?

Comment: @Ваня в таких случаях нужно анализировать стек вызовов. Код класса Scanner открыт для вас.

Comment: В трёх)

Comment: Насчет i не страшно.

Comment: Не нужно, достаточно внимательно посмотреть на текст программы.

Comment: shurik, цикл не вложенный, просто отступы сами собой появились)
Angry Bird, в код сканера я не полезу, рановато ещё, только начал язык изучать
Kremchik, что?
avp, спасибо, действительно дело в алгоритме

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1):

1) Стек надо создать. Например: st = new Stack();

2) При всех операциях со стеком используйте приведение типа к Integer. Например:  b[i] = (Integer)st.peek(); Иначе, у меня вообще не компилируется.

3) При самом первом обращении стек пуст, это вызывает java.util.EmptyStackException.
Пересмотрите Ваш алгоритм.

Что в алгоритме не так, я разбираться не стал, т.к. задача не сформулирована.