# Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?

Tags: java, faq, java-faq

Что из себя представляет исключение Null Pointer Exception (`java.lang.NullPointerException`) и почему оно может происходить?

Какие методы и средства использовать, чтобы определить причину возникновения этого исключения, приводящего к преждевременному прекращению работы приложения?

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/)» [@Ziggy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29182/ziggy).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Когда вы объявляете переменную ссылочного типа, на самом деле вы создаете ссылку на объект данного типа. Рассмотрим следующий код для объявления переменной типа int:

```
int x;
x = 10;
```

В этом примере переменная `x` имеет тип `int` и Java инициализирует её как 0. Когда вы присвоите переменной значение 10 (вторая строка), это значение сохранится в ячейке памяти, на которую ссылается `x`.

Но когда вы объявляете ссылочный тип, процесс выглядит иначе. Посмотрим на следующий код:

```
Integer num;
num = new Integer(10);
```

В первой строке объявлена переменная `num`, ее тип не относится к встроенному, следовательно, значением является ссылка (тип этой переменной, `Integer`, является ссылочным типом). Поскольку вы еще не указали, на что собираетесь ссылаться, Java присвоит переменной значение `Null`, подразумевая «Я ни на что не ссылаюсь».

Во второй строке, ключевое слово `new` используется для создания объекта типа `Integer`. Этот объект имеет адрес в памяти, который присваивается переменной `num`. Теперь, с помощью переменной `num` вы можете обратиться к объекту используя оператора разыменования `.`.

Исключение, о котором вы говорите в вопросе, возникает, если вы объявили переменную, но не создали объект, то есть если вы попытаетесь разыменовать `num` *до того*, как создали объект, вы получите `NullPointerException`. В самом простом случае, компилятор обнаружит проблему и сообщит, что

> `num` may not have been initialized

Что говорит: «возможно, переменная `num` не инициализирована».

Иногда исключение вызвано именно тем, что объект действительно не был создан. К примеру, у вас может быть следующая функция:

```
public void doSomething(Integer num){
   // Работаем с num
}
```

В этом случае создание объекта (переменная `num`) лежит на вызывающем коде, то есть вы предполагаете, что он был создан ранее – до вызова метода `doSomething`. К сожалению, следующий вызов метода вполне возможен:

```
doSomething(null);
```

В этом случае значение переменной `num` будет `null`. Лучшим способом избежать данного исключения будет проверка на равенство нулю. Как результат, функция `doSomething` должна быть переписана следующим образом:

```
public void doSomething(Integer num){
    if (num != null) {
       // Работаем с num
    }
}
```

Как альтернативный вариант предыдущему примеру вы можете сообщить вызывающему коду, что метод был вызван с неверными параметрами, например, с помощью `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
public void doSomething(Integer num){
    if (num == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Num не должен быть null"); 
    // Работаем с num
}
```

Также, обратите внимание на вопрос «[Что такое stack trace и как с его помощью находить ошибки при разработке приложений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/)».

<sub>Перевод ответа «[What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/564240)» [@Vincent Ramdhanie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27439/vincent-ramdhanie).</sub>

Comment: А ещё настаивают, чтобы делали так `public void doSomething(Integer num){
    if (num == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("аргумент num не должен быть null"); ...
}`

Comment: @Sergey Отличное уточнение, спасибо! Внес в ответ.

Comment: а аннотации типа @NonNull ? Они по-моему лучше отражают намерение.

Comment: Раз уж в метках Java, а на дворе 2016й, стоит в способы борьбы с NPE добавить [Optional](https://habrahabr.ru/post/225641/)

Comment: Можно и [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-) вспомнить. "may not have been initialized" - это немного про другое. В java поля объекта без явного инциализатора заполняются значениями по-умолчанию (`null` для ссылочных типов), а локальные переменные - нет. Сообщение "may not have been initialized" говорит о том, что существует путь выполнения, при котором переменной никогда не присваивается значение. Получить NPE в таком коде нельзя, т.к. он просто не скомпилируется.

Comment: Как альтернативу, можно использовать assert num!=null.

Comment: А где самый простейший вариант решения проблемы - инициализировать-таки переменную? Большинство проблем с NPE правильно решаются именно так...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Пожалуйста, дополните ответ или напишите свой!

Answer (score 13):

В **java8** был добавлен класс `Optional` для предотвращения `NullPointerException`, хотя использовать его по назначению не всегда удается правильно. Вот [ссылка](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-991686) с рекомендациями как использовать `Optional`

Типичное решение с проверкой на `null`

```
Article article = getFirstJavaArticle();

    if (article == null) {
        article = fetchLatestArticle();
    }
```

А теперь решение с использованием `Optional<T>`. Представим что `getFirstJavaArticle()` возвращает `Optional<Article>`

```
getFirstJavaArticle()  
    .orElseGet(this::fetchLatestArticle);
```

Решение с `Optional` позволяет нам избежать кода с проверками на `null`  и работать в функциональном стиле. Стоит заметить что Optional [не является панацеей от всех бед](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555)

> Так же для предотвращения `NullPointerException` используется паттерн
>   [NullObject](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

**Абстрактный `Entity class`**

```
public abstract class AbstractCustomer {
    protected String name;
    public abstract String getName();
}
```

**Реальная реализация**

```
public class RealCustomer extends AbstractCustomer {

   public RealCustomer(String name) {
      this.name = name;     
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

**Реализация `NullObject`**

```
public class NullCustomer extends AbstractCustomer {

   @Override
   public String getName() {
      return "Not Available in Customer Database";
   }
 }
```

**Использование (как пример)**

```
public class CustomerFactory {

   public static final String[] names = {"Rob", "Joe", "Julie"};

   public static AbstractCustomer getCustomer(String name){

      for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
         if (names[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            return new RealCustomer(name);
         }
      }
      return new NullCustomer();
   }
}
```

Вместо возвращения `null` мы возвращаем экземпляр класс `NullCustomer` и не падаем с `NullPointerException`. Но как мне кажется присутствует небольшой Overhead: необходимо создавать иерархию наследования.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы прямо в ответе здесь на сайте раскрыть информацию, на которую вы ссылаетесь, [в минимальном необходимом виде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

Советую использовать `Optional` для предотвращения NPE. Этот класс был введене в java 8.

К примеру

```
 @Entity
 public class Car {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  @NotNull
  private String name;
}
```

Репозиторий:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {

  Optional<Car> findById(Long id);

}
```

Сервис:

```
@Service
public class CarService {

  private CarRepository carRepository;

  @Autowired
  public CarService(CarRepository carRepository) {
    this.carRepository = carRepository;
  }

 public Car findById(Long id) {
    Car car = carRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() ->
        new RuntimeException("Requested entity was not found"));
    car.getHolder().setPassword(null);
    return car;
  }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CarController {

  private CarService carService;

  @Autowired
  public CarController(CarService carService) {
    this.carService = carService;
  }

@RequestMapping(value = "/cars/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<Car> getCar(@PathVariable Long id) {
    try {
      Car carToFind = carService.findById(id);
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(carToFind);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
  }
}
```

В таком случае, если репозиторий не сможет найти машину, он не выкинет NPE.
`Optional` помогает избежать проверок на `null` и сократить код и улучшить его читаемостью.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky добавил код, можете посмотреть.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Это Exception , который встречается тогда, когда ты ссылаешься на объект, который = null(не инициализирован) или пытаешься вызвать методы/обратиться к переменным объекта, который = null. Решение этой проблемы:

1. Проверка на null, `if(Твой объект==null){//Your code}`
2. `try{}catch(NullPointerException e){//Your code}`
3. Когда тебе выбрасывает нулл,то обычно указывает "иерархию строчек"(что, как вызывалось, что привело тебя к нулл). И там ты можешь посмотреть, где у тебя объект не инициализирован, там и можно сразу исправить ошибку.
4. Может встречаться в массивах/списках, когда вызываешь объект под номер n, при том, что объекта туда предварительно не записан.
   Вроде, все))

Comment: За (2) могут запросто уволить. И в целом ответ не добавляет решительно ничего нового по сравнению с тем, что уже есть.

Comment: за второе могут уволить, но вообще если, например, идет работа на сервере 24/7 при этом выскакивает нулл, то после блока кетч можно предложить решение(записать ошибку в лог/консоль(хотя так мало, кто делает), тогда можно прочитать лог и разобраться с ошибками, так что этот вариант тоже имеет право быть

Comment: @SmartSystem записывать в лог отдельный NPE не имеет смысла никогда. Если ловить исключение для записи в лог - то только на самом верхнем уровне и только Exception или Throwable.

Comment: Это одно из возможных преобразований, естественно, что в лог нужно писать все траблы, а не только конкретные,  в моем комменте выше имелось  в виду все ошибки, а не только нул, нул  я как пример привел