# Ошибка Attempt to invoke virtual method '...' on a null object reference

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragment

Только разбираюсь с Android.
Есть фрагмент:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    SQLiteOpenHelper deck_helper = new DeckDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase db = deck_helper.getReadableDatabase();
    TextView name = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Cursor cursor = db.query("DECK", new String[]{"NAME"}, "_id=?",
            new String[]{Integer.toString(1)}, null, null, null);
        try {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String nameText = cursor.getString(0);
                name.setText(nameText);

            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deck_manager, container, false);
}
```

Хочу, чтобы textView заполнялось из базы данных столбцом `Name`.
Вот класс DeckDatabaseHelper:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DECK (" + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "NAME TEXT, "
            + "CLASS TEXT, "
            +  "IMAGE_CLASS INTEGER"
            + ");");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("NAME", "Mage");
    values.put("CLASS", "Mage");
    values.put("IMAGE_CLASS", "123");
    db.insert("DECK",null,values);

}
```

При открытии фрагмента получаю ошибку:

> ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at com.example.nikolaypavlin.deck.Fragments.DeckManagerFragment.onCreateView(DeckManagerFragment.java:57)

UPD.
Новый код фрагмента:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deck_manager, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    SQLiteOpenHelper deck_helper = new DeckDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase db = deck_helper.getReadableDatabase();
    TextView name = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Cursor cursor = db.query("DECK", new String[]{"NAME"}, "_id=?",
            new String[]{Integer.toString(1)}, null, null, null);
        try {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String nameText = cursor.getString(0);
                name.setText(nameText);

            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    return view;
}
```

Разметка:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nikolaypavlin.deck.Fragments.DeckManagerFragment">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте официальную документацию прежде чем что-то сделать наугад, тем более что основные моменты переведенны на русский язык. В данный момент вам необходимо прочитать раздел про [фрагменты](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html). Метод `onCreateView` фрагмента предназначен для создания корневого элемента пользовательского интерфейса фрагмента. Т.е. в нем первым делом вы создаете `view` которая будет отображаться, а в конце вы должны вернуть эту `view` из этого метода. Вы же зачем то пытаетесь искать ваши `view` в активити вызывая `getActivity().findViewById()`. Очевидно что их там нету, и данный метод возвращает `null`, но вы пытаетесь установить в них какие-то значения после чего и вылетает `NullPointerException`. Что это такое можете почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511085/181119).

В вашем случае ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deck_manager, container, false);

    //ищем и настраиваем view
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    /*
        Остальной код   
    */
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Переделал по вашим советам, ошибка осталась.

Comment: @NikolayPavlin разметку покажите

Comment: @NikolayPavlin и код который вы написали в ```onCreateView```

Comment: Обновил основной вопрос.

Comment: @NikolayPavlin внимательней смотрите, текстовое поле все еще ищется в активити