# Я никак не могу сделать в fragment'e кнопку для перехода в activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, android-intent

Я понимаю что ошибка в строке return, но как из соединить?

```
public class FragmentAll extends Fragment {

    Button bPluss;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private void findViewById(int bLogin) {
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentAll() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentAll.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentAll newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentAll fragment = new FragmentAll();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);

        bPluss = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bPluss);

        bPluss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(FragmentAll.this.getActivity(), CreateActivity.class);
                FragmentAll.this.getActivity().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Comment: А где у вас starActivity(Intent)?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка Attempt to invoke virtual method '...' on a null object reference](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514856/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-object-reference)

Comment: Покажите больше кода.

Answer (score 1):

Эта строка не нужна, удалите. Нельзя сделать два return подряд

> return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);

После создания интента, активити надо запустить:

```
FragmentAll.this.getActivity().starActivity(intent)
```

Comment: @VеселыйМалый, если один из ответов отвечает на вопрос, то вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)

Comment: ЮрийСПБ, без этого кода он вылетает return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);

Comment: @VеселыйМалый, у вас в начале метода прописано `rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);`?

Comment: Я по другому прописал, вот: View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);

Comment: @VеселыйМалый, выдавайте больше информации в сообщениях. В данный момент непонятно есть ли у вас ошибка, какая она, что вы изменили в коде. Так вам помочь сложно. Другие же не видят весь ваш код и вывод оного в логи.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, Щас добавлю весь код Fragment'a

Comment: @VеселыйМалый, так а не работает-то сейчас что?.. Если есть ошибка - приведите её тип, строку возниковения и stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны в rootView присвоить inflated.inflate...

```
rootView = inflated.inflate(R.layout.qwer, container, false)

return rootView;
```

Comment: Это в Фрагменте я прописал

Comment: @VеселыйМалый значит вам нужно проделать то что написал ЮрийСПБ выше и все