# Программа работает, но бросает исключение NullPointerException

Tags: java, исключения

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends JFrame{

public Game(){
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.paint(null);
}

}
```

Comment: Ну вы же сами передаёте `null`.

Comment: game.paint(null);

Comment: Я просто не могу понять, как сделать по другому. Graphics - абстрактный класс и экземпляров не создает... А если пытаться создать потомок класса, нужно кучу методов переопределять...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По поводу исключения `NPE` можно и нужно прочитать здесь: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-null-pointer-exception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Нет смысла сюда копировать такой большой текст.

Про `awt` и метод `paint` можно сказать следующее: 
движок `awt` вызывает метод `paint` каждый раз, когда оперативная система сообщает, что надо нарисовать что-то на холсте. Он вызывается когда в самый первый раз создается окно или когда минимизируем/максимизируем окно, изменям размер мышкой и т.д.
Такие сообщения отсылаются постоянно, неявно, виртуальной машиной. И, как следствие, вызывать его нет нужды.

Т.е. в вашем случае достаточно написать

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
}
```

Создастся окно и автоматически подхватится `paint`

Answer (score 3):

Вам просто не нужно вызывать paint(), он вызывается неявно виртуальной машиной.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!