# Инициализация переменных и передача

Tags: java, global-variables

Ребят подскажите, есть класс, в нём переменные:

```
double[][] weightIH;
double[][] weightHO;
```

Значение по умолчание их null, есть метод где значения этих переменных инициализируются:

```
void test() {
    weightIH = new double[1 + NUM_IN][NUM_HID];
    weightHO = new double[1 + NUM_HID][NUM_OUT];
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_HID; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 1 + NUM_IN; i++) 
            weightIH[i][j] = 2.0 * (randomize() - 0.5) * smallwt;

    for (int k = 0; k < NUM_OUT; k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 1 + NUM_HID; j++)
            weightHO[j][k] = 2.0 * (randomize() - 0.5) * smallwt;
}
```

Затем, имеется класс где нужны значения этих переменных:

```
class Training {
    void name() {
      Network network = new Network();
        for (int j = 0; j < numHidden; j++) {
            sumH[j] = network.weightHO[0][j];
            for (int i = 0; i < numInput; i++)
                sumH[j] += input[p][i] * network.weightIH[1 + i][j];
            hidden[j] = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-sumH[j]));
        }
    }
}
```

После запуска, ловлю NullPointerException, т.е. в классе Training переменные weightIH и weightOH равны null.

Как решить проблему с передачей значений переменных, без null?

Comment: так нет вызова метода `void test()` поэтому переменные и не инициализируются. И вообще наверно лучше инициализировать значения в конструкторе. Т.е. в  классе `Network` делать конструктор в котором инициализировать данный переменные.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Update: у вас требуемые массивы не хранят никаких значений. они лишь проинициализированы были, т.е. под них выделилось место. А значений не лежат там, в итоге при обращении к элементам массивов возвращается `null`

Comment: Забыл код добавить для заполнение, они инициализируются и заполняются в методе.
Вызов методов в main сначала метод с test() а потом уже и метод из класса Training name()

Comment: в вашем методе `Training.name` создается отдельный объект `Network`. То что вы где-то там в `main` у какого-то другого объекта что-то вызвали на него не влияет. Возможно, вам стоит изменить метод `name()` на `name( Network network )` и передавать нужный объект в качестве параметра.

Comment: Спасибо, думал если у main вызвать будет влиять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ты создаешь объект, но не иницилизируешь методом test()

```
class Training {
    void name() {
      Network network = new Network();
// после этого нужно вызвать метод инициализации 
        network.test();
// дальше будут работать
        for (int j = 0; j < numHidden; j++) {
            sumH[j] = network.weightHO[0][j];
            for (int i = 0; i < numInput; i++)
                sumH[j] += input[p][i] * network.weightIH[1 + i][j];
            hidden[j] = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-sumH[j]));
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. не пойму почему код не добавляется нормально

Comment: а т.е. нужно в классе Training нужно создать Объект и просто вызвать test() и null пропадет?
Почему же тогда в main не работает, я вызываю test() а затем и name() ?

Comment: @Цовак Саакян Нужно выделить текст и нажать `Ctrl+K` или кнопку на панели

Comment: либо одиночный кавычки обратный используешь(который на кнопке с Ё) либо отступ. а вообще справка там есть и кнопки для форматирования)

Comment: спасибо большое. у меня исчезла меню с кнопками форматирования. но после обновления страницы все норм получилось

Answer (score 1):

1. у вас требуемые массивы не хранят никаких значений. они лишь сами проинициализированы были, т.е. под них выделилось место. А значений не лежат там, в итоге при обращении к элементам массивов возвращается `null`
2. Нет вызова метода void test() для объекта  `Network`, поэтому переменные и не инициализируются. И вообще наверно лучше инициализировать значения в конструкторе. Т.е. в классе Network делать конструктор в котором инициализировать данный переменные

Comment: ой извините забыл добавить код заполение значений