# Почему падает приложение при переходе на fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, button

В приложении два фрагмента. Второй по структуре идентичен первому. Вызываются из меню дровера. Первый и второй открываются без проблем. Но как только добавляю обработчик нажатия кнопки во втором при открывании фрагмента с этой кнопкой приложение падает.
Код фрагмента:
public class FragmentTanks extends Fragment {

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public static final double pi = 3.1415926535;

Animation anim_show;
Animation anim_hide;

//Раздел объявления Layout
//****************************************
LinearLayout L_tanks_flow_wash;
LinearLayout L_tanks_volume_solution;


//Раздел объявления Button
//****************************************
Button btn_tanks_flow_wash;
Button btn_tanks_flow_wash_calculate;

Button btn_tanksF_volume_solution;
Button L_tanks_volume_solution_calculate;


// Раздел объявления EditText и Spinner
//****************************************
EditText et_tanksF_diameter;
EditText et_tanks_angle_spray;
EditText et_tanks_current_flow;
Spinner sp_tanks_pollution_level;
EditText et_tanks_estimated_flow;

EditText et_tanksV_diameter;
EditText et_tanks_cone_height;
EditText et_tanks_cylinder_height;
EditText et_tanks_volume_solution;


public FragmentTanks() {
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tanks, container, false);

    anim_show = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim_show);
    anim_hide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim_hide);


    //region Поток на мойку танка

    //Раздел инициализации Layout
    //****************************************
    L_tanks_flow_wash = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.L_tanks_flow_wash);


    // Раздел инициализации Button
    //****************************************
    btn_tanks_flow_wash = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_tanks_flow_wash);
    btn_tanks_flow_wash_calculate = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pipes_flowD_calculate);


    // Раздел инициализации EditText и Spinner
    //****************************************
    et_tanksF_diameter = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_tanksF_diameter);
    et_tanks_angle_spray = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_tanks_angle_spray);
    et_tanks_current_flow = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_tanks_current_flow);
    sp_tanks_pollution_level = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp_tanks_pollution_level);
    et_tanks_estimated_flow = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_tanks_estimated_flow);


    btn_tanks_flow_wash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (btn_tanks_flow_wash.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                hide(L_tanks_flow_wash);
            } else {
                show(L_tanks_flow_wash);
            }

        }
    });

    btn_tanks_flow_wash_calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Норм!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    //endregion


    return rootView;
}
```

}

Разметка фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="ru.zets_swe.calculator.fragments.FragmentTanks">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dp">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_tanks_flow_wash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tv_tanks_the_flow_to_the_sink_tanks" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_tanks_flow_wash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:shrinkColumns="0"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:textAlignment="center">


                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/table_text"
                        android:text="@string/tv_tanks_diameter" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/table_text"
                        android:text="@string/tv_tanks_angle_spray" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/table_text"
                        android:text="@string/tv_tanks_current_flow" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/table_text"
                        android:text="@string/tv_tanks_pollution_level" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/table_text"
                        android:text="@string/tv_tanks_estimated_flow" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_tanksF_diameter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="1"
                        android:hint="0"
                        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_tanks_angle_spray"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="1"
                        android:hint="0"
                        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_tanks_current_flow"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="1"
                        android:hint="0"
                        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />

<!--                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_tanks_pollution_level"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:editable="true"
                        android:ems="1"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:inputType="number" />-->

                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/sp_tanks_pollution_level"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_tanks_estimated_flow"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:editable="true"
                        android:ems="1"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:inputType="number" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_tanks_flow_wash_calculate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="@string/btn_text_calculate" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_tanksF_volume_solution"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tv_tanks_volume_of_the_solution_in_the_tank" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_tanks_volume_solution"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:shrinkColumns="0"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:textAlignment="center">


                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/table_text"
                        android:text="@string/tv_tanks_diameter" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/table_text"
                        android:text="@string/tv_tanks_cone_height" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/table_text"
                        android:text="@string/tv_tanks_cylinder_height" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/table_text"
                        android:text="@string/tv_tanks_volume_solution" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_tanksV_diameter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="1"
                        android:hint="0"
                        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_tanks_cone_height"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="1"
                        android:hint="0"
                        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_tanks_cylinder_height"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="1"
                        android:hint="0"
                        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_tanks_volume_solution"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:editable="true"
                        android:ems="1"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:inputType="number" />

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/L_tanks_volume_solution_calculate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="@string/btn_text_calculate" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Если убрать btn_tanks_flow_wash_calculate то все работает. Где может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас `btn_tanks_flow_wash_calculate = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pipes_flowD_calculate);`, а в разметке `btn_pipes_flowD_calculate` *отсутствует*. Поэтому, если убрать `btn_tanks_flow_wash_calculate` то все работает.

P.S. в дальнейшем (Надеюсь, не пригодится) лучше выкладывайте еще и код ошибки, а не только километровый код:)

P.P.S "Копипаста зло =(" (c) - Это точно.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Копипаста зло =(

Comment: @АлександрТымчук Рад был помочь! Если ответ помог, то не забудьте отметить галочкой рядом с моим ответом слева:)