# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview, cardview

Обучался вот по этому [Уроку](http://www.fandroid.info/android-uchebnik-sozdanie-recyclerview-cardview-i-menyu-optsij-dlya-elementa-recyclerview/), и по нему все работает. Проблема в следующем: мне надо сделать тоже самое, но с применением фрагментов. Разметку и код Адаптера я оставил такие же, а из главного Активити перенес код в класс наследующий Fragment. У меня это выглядит так:

```
import android.content.Context;     
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass extends Fragment{
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private List<RecyclerItem> listItems;
private Context context;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout,null);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) x.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        listItems.add(new RecyclerItem("Item " + (i + 1), ""+ i + 1 );
    }
    adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, context);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return x;
}}
```

Все отображает нормально, но при нажатии на меню выбивает ошибку в Адаптере

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

в этой строке:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, holder.txtOptionDigit);
```

Полный код Адаптера:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<RecyclerItem> listItems;
private Context context;

public RecyclerAdapter(List<RecyclerItem> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final RecyclerItem itemList = listItems.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(itemList.getTitle());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(itemList.getDescription());
    holder.txtOptionDigit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, holder.txtOptionDigit);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.option_menu);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.mnu_item_save:
                            break;
                        case R.id.mnu_item_delete:    
                            listItems.remove(position);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView txtTitle;
    public TextView txtDescription;
    public TextView txtOptionDigit;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        txtDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        txtOptionDigit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtOptionDigit);
    }
}}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем тут дело.

Comment: И почитайте что такое NPE тут: [Что-такое-null-pointer-exception-и-как-его-исправить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511085/17609)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не инициализирована переменная `context`, которую вы передаёте в адаптер. А её в адаптер вообще, в общем-то, передавать и не надо. Вы можете получить контекст из любой `View`, которая есть в холдере. Т.е. вам надо:

1. Удалить переменную `Context context` из фрагмента.
2. Удалить переменную `Context context` из адаптера.
3. Удалить аргумент `Context context` из конструктора адаптера.
4. Удалить передачу удалённой переменной `context` из аргумента адаптера при его создании во фрагменте
5. Создать переменную `Context context` в `onBindViewholder` методе адаптера.
6. Инициализировать её контекстом, взятым из `View`, которая есть в холдере так:

```
context = holder.itemView.getContext();
```

---

И почитайте что такое NPE тут: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511085/17609)