# NullPointerException SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jtable, preparedstatement

Выбрасывает исключение **java.lang.NullPointerException** в строке `stm = cn.createStatement();`

```
public static void printTable(Connection cn){
        PreparedStatement   pstmt = null;
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet            rs    = null;

        DefaultTableModel   dtm   = null;
        try{
            stm = cn.createStatement(); //exception
            System.out.println("Успешно удалено");

        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Ошибка createStatement");
            return;
        }
        try{

            stm.execute("USE mars");
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Ошибка use");
            return;
        }
        try {
            pstmt = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT id_code, type, name, manufacturer, provider, quantity FROM goods");

        dtm   = new DefaultTableModel();

        if(pstmt.execute()) {
            rs = pstmt.getResultSet(); 
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData(); 
            for(int col = 1; col <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); col++)
                dtm.addColumn(rsmd.getColumnName(col)); 
            while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<String>  row = new Vector<String>(); //Строка таблицы

            for(int col = 1; col <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); col++) {                        

                int type = rsmd.getColumnType(col);

                switch(type) {

                    case Types.INTEGER :
                        row.add(new Integer(rs.getInt(col)).toString());
                        break;

                    case Types.VARCHAR :
                        row.add(rs.getString(col));
                        break;

                    default :

                        throw new Exception("Неподдерживаемый тип");
                }

            }                                    

            dtm.addRow(row);
        }
    }   
        }

catch (SQLException ex) {            
    System.out.println(ex.toString());


} catch (Exception e) {            
    e.printStackTrace();
}
JTable      grid = new JTable();

        grid.setModel(dtm);
JScrollPane jsp  = new JScrollPane(grid);

        Signed.frame_main.add(jsp);          
    }
```

Вызываю метод в другом классе, в main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        cnctn = Main.conn(); //тут подключение к базе (подключается нормально)
        Main.printTable(cnctn); //exception
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{

                    Signed window_reg = new Signed();
                    Signed.frame_main.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e2){
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
});
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Вы не инициализировали `cn` он у вас null

Comment: @Victor, а, ну да, надо же драйвер менеджером, спасибо

Comment: Вопрос то удалить можно, никакой ценности он не несёт!

Answer (score 2):

А где метод conn? Возможна вутри этого метода какая та пойманный ексепшн и метод возврашшает null.

```
cnctn = Main.conn();
```

Comment: Это я должен был написать на коммент но не хватает баллов