# NullPointerException EventFragment.java:99

Tags: java, android

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста!

Ошибка возникает при взаимодействии следующих двух фрагментов:
Во фрагменте `EventFragment`, (который назначен целевым) есть кнопка,  которая должна содержать введенную дату. По событию `onClick()` создается новый фрагмент `DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment`,

```
mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mEvent.getDate());
        dialog.setTargetFragment(EventFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
        dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_DATE);
    }
});
```

Во фрагменте `DatePickerFragment` внутри `DialogAlert'а` с одной positive-кнопкой располагается `DatePicker`.

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setView(inflatedView)
        .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
                        int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
                        int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                        Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day).getTime();
                        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date);
                    }
                }
        )
        .create();
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку "ок" вызывается метод `sendResult()` куда передается `Acitivity.RESULT_OK` а также новая дата, в самом в методе создается интент и отправляется обратно в первый фрагмент, в метод `onActivityResult(...)`

```
private void sendResult (int resultCode, Date date){
    if (getTargetFragment() == null){
        return;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, date);
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
}
```

Но как только процесс выполнения доходит до строки `getTargetFragment()...` возникает ошибка `NullPointerException`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в строке №99 файла `EventFragment.java`, а не `AlertController.java`

Для информации [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511085/205238)

Comment: Точно! Спасибо огромное! Я думал в журнале надо начинать с последней строки искать ошибку O_o

Comment: @MisterSmith Иерархия вызовов всегда идёт сверху вниз, от дочернего к родителю. Если ответ вам был полезен - не забудьте его принять

Comment: Конечно! Извините, а как принять ответ? Нажать на верхний треугольник ?

Comment: @MisterSmith, ✔ под баллами за ответ. И ещё вот [гид по сайту](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Разобрался! Спасибо! )