# NullPointerException при добавлении в лист

Tags: android, list

Из активити вызываю метод в фрагменте:

```
fragmentContact = new FragmentContact();
fragmentContact.dataAdd(name, number, email);
```

Методом в фрагменте добавляю в лист объект и обновляю адаптер:

```
public void dataAdd(String name, String number, String email) {
    contactsList.add(new Contacts(name, number, email));
    Collections.sort(contactsList, new Contacts.SortBeName());
    mAdapter.dataChanged(contactsList);
}
```

`Exception` в этой строчке:

```
contactsList.add(new Contacts(name, number, email));
```

Comment: Логично предположить, что contactsList не инициализирован

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511086/245626

Comment: Создавая новый экземпляр фрагмента вы не получаете доступ к тому, который на экране отображается. Наверное, вам таки нужно к фрагменту на экране обратиться. Если так, то ищите его через `FragmentManager`