# Как правильно отловить исключение NullPointerException в Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, исключения

Привет. Правильно ли я отлавливаю исключение `NullPointerException` в данном случае или существуют другие, более короткие способы?

```
try {
    try {
        numBytesRead = mPort.read(buffer, 1000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}catch (NullPointerException e)
{}
```

Причем проверка `mPort` на `null` не подходит, потому что ошибка периодически возникает, когда я разрываю соединение со своим USB устройством, которое в этот момент слало данные, при этом `mPort` еще существует, а вот внутри метода `read` вызывается исключение.

Спасибо.

Comment: Зачем вложенные try? Оставь один блок try и подряд напиши несколько catch(...)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-null-pointer-exception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Незачем делать каскад try, можно последовательно описать обработку разных исключений:

```
    try {
        numBytesRead = mPort.read(buffer, 1000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Ещё есть multicatch (спасибо Regent за напоминание), если вы хотите несколько типов исключений обрабатывать одинаково:

```
    try {
        numBytesRead = mPort.read(buffer, 1000);
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerExceptione) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал, что есть такая конструкция :)

Comment: @GlWhitefoot если исключения предполагается обрабатывать одинаково, то достаточно не только одного `try`, но и одного `catch`: `catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`.

Comment: @Regent мда, совсем я забыл джаву. ))

Comment: @Regent android не поддерживает java 8

Comment: @Соколов а как это связано с Multi-catch exceptions, [появившимися в Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html)?

Comment: @Regent сори имел виду 7 версию (по крайней мере у меня)

Comment: @Соколов судя по [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21700827/3432401) (уже достаточно старому), проблем с Java 7 в Android быть не должно, особенно при неиспользовании try-with-resources. В своей игре я использую древнюю версию Java для кроссплатформенного кода (с учетом того что есть клиент для JavaME), так что практическим опытом подтвердить это не могу.

Answer (score 6):

Не делайте вот так:

```
catch (NullPointerException e) { }
```

если в этом действительно нет необходимости.

Если, при возникновении `NullPointerException` **действительно** ничего не должно происходить, то можете как-то явно это указать, например:

```
catch (NullPointerException ignored) { }
```

Нет необходимости во вложенном `try-catch`. Возникшие исключение можно обработать в одном блоке:

```
try {
    numBytesRead = mPort.read(buffer, 1000);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Учтите, что в блоках с несколькими `catch` сначала следует обрабатывать более *узкие* исключения.

Comment: Плюс за `ignored`.

Answer (score 6):

Эмм..., а нельзя как-то попроще?

```
try {
    if(mPort != null)
        numBytesRead = mPort.read(buffer, 1000);
    else
        Log.w(TAG, "Port is zero!");

} catch (Throwable th) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Something went wrong reading from port", th);
}
```

Зачем доводить до NPE - try/catch достаточно дорогостоящая операция, а сравнение на `null` это вообще ни о чем.

Ну и второе, зачем писать `printStackTrace()` - надо использовать встроенное логирование.

Если так уж хотите вылавливать все исключения - надо ловить `Throwable`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но на таком примере я тестировал. Иногда в момент выдергивания провода УСБ из устройства эти проверки не проходят, возникает ошибка внутри метода read.

Comment: А тут плюс за логирование )

Comment: Обновил ответ - тогда вам надо ловить `Throwable`