# Почему вылетает NullPointerException при использовании JavaRDD?

Tags: java

Взял пример [отсюда](https://github.com/SkymindIO/screencasts/blob/master/datavec_spark_transform/StormReportsRecordReader.java), изменил только папку baseDir, файл в нее положил. Постоянно появляется ошибка: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException. Ругается на последнюю строку, файл нужный не записывается.

```
public class StormReportsRecordReader {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        int numLinesToSkip = 0;
        String delimiter = ",";

        /**
         * Specify the root directory
         * If you are working from home replace baseDir
         * with the location you downloaded the reports.csv
         * file to.
         */

        String baseDir = "/Users/storm/";
        String fileName = "reports.csv";
        String inputPath = baseDir + fileName;
        String timeStamp = String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
        String outputPath = baseDir + "reports_processed_" + timeStamp;

        /**
         * Data file looks like this
         * 161006-1655,UNK,2 SE BARTLETT,LABETTE,KS,37.03,-95.19,
         * TRAINED SPOTTER REPORTS TORNADO ON THE GROUND. (ICT),TOR
         * Fields are
         * datetime,severity,location,county,state,lat,lon,comment,type
         */

        Schema inputDataSchema = new Schema.Builder()
                .addColumnsString("datetime","severity","location","county","state")
                .addColumnsDouble("lat","lon")
                .addColumnsString("comment")
                .addColumnCategorical("type","TOR","WIND","HAIL")
                .build();


        /**
         * Define a transform process to extract lat and lon
         * and also transform type from one of three strings
         * to either 0,1,2
         */


        TransformProcess tp = new TransformProcess.Builder(inputDataSchema)
                .removeColumns("datetime","severity","location","county","state","comment")
                .categoricalToInteger("type")
                .build();
/**
 * Some code to step through and print the before
 * and after Schema
 */

        int numActions = tp.getActionList().size();
        for (int i = 0; i<numActions; i++){
            System.out.println("\n\n===============================");
            System.out.println("--- Schema after step " + i +
            " (" + tp.getActionList().get(i) + ")--" );
            System.out.println(tp.getSchemaAfterStep(i));
        }

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]");
        sparkConf.setAppName("Storm Reports Record Reader Transform");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        /**
         * Get our data into a spark RDD
         * and transform that spark RDD using our
         * transform process
         */

        // read the data file
        JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(inputPath);
        // convert to Writable
        JavaRDD<List<Writable>> stormReports = lines.map(new StringToWritablesFunction(new CSVRecordReader()));
        // run our transform process
        JavaRDD<List<Writable>> processed = SparkTransformExecutor.execute(stormReports,tp);
        // convert Writable back to string for export
        JavaRDD<String> toSave= processed.map(new WritablesToStringFunction(","));

        toSave.saveAsTextFile(outputPath);


    }

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вопрос не «откуда вообще берётся `NullPointerException`», а «почему она вылетает при работе с файлом».

Comment: @Arhad "Что такое Null Pointer Exception **и как его исправить**?"

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите полный путь к директории с файлом ("./Users/storm/"), если же вы запускаете через студию, то укажите рабочую дирректорию проекта.