# Ошибка при работе с ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

Доброго вечера!
Столкнулся с ошибкой:

```
lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Никак не могу понять как ее устранить, хелп!
Код:

```
public class History extends Fragment {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; // Создаём адаптер ArrayAdapter, чтобы привязать массив к ListView
    ArrayList<String> history = new ArrayList<>();

    // Создаём пустой массив для хранения имен котов

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false); //открываем вьюху чтоб найти нужные нам элементы на ней

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv);

        history.add("5");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, history);

        // Привяжем массив через адаптер к ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void AddHistory (String text){
        Log.d("---------ADDHISTORY",text);
        adapter.add(text);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка происходит на данном этапе `adapter.add(text)`. Выложите полный код если не трудно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085

Comment: Метод `AddHistory` вызывается до того как был вызван метод `onCreateView`. Смотрите по вашему коду где и почему это происходит.

Comment: Ошибка в том где или когда вы вызываете `AddHistory` метод.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)