# Не удается установить соединение с базой данных jdbc tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

```
public class Connect {

    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gregs_list?" +
        "useUnicode=true&useSSL=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true" +
        "&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    private final String USERNAME = "root";
    private final String PASSWORD = "root";

    private Connection connection;

    public Connection getConnect(){
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.
                getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Servlets

```
public class ServletGlobal extends HttpServlet {
private Connect connect;
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponseresponse)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try(Connection connection = connect.getConnect();
        PreparedStatement prt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user");
        ResultSet rs = prt.executeQuery()) {

        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("user_id"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("user_name"));
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("user_age"));
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("user_salary"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Ошибка:

```
04-Feb-2018 22:07:39.170 SEVERE [http-nio-9000-exec-6] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for 
servlet [Servant] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mycompany.app.logic.ServletGlobal.doGet(ServletGlobal.java:28)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Servant</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.mycompany.app.logic.ServletGlobal</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Servant</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rer</url-pattern>
```

я создал минимальный код для проверки, и даже это не работает. Падает на строке когда я пытаюсь получить connection. И ошибка при том вылетает в tomcat LocalHost Log

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где инициализация переменной `private Connect connect;` в классе `ServletGlobal` ? И поскольку ругается на 28 строку, помечайте ее в вопросе.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: А если написать так private Connect connect = new Connect ();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что переменная `Connect connect` не инициализирована.
Как вам предлагали в комментариях, вы можете инициализировать ее `Connect connect = new Connect ();`, но это будет не совсем верно.
Во-первых, вам придет во всех местах, где требуется экземпляр подключения, создавать экземпляр `Connect`. Как следствие, 2й, более серьезный недостаток - у вас не будет единого места управления подключениями и контролировать их будет невозможно (например, количество подключений).

Класс `Connect` в вашем случае это типичный пример фабричного паттерна. Есть несколько вариантов реализации, в вашем случае самый простой - статическая фабрика:

```
public final class ConnectionManager {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gregs_list?" +
            "useUnicode=true&useSSL=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true" +
            "&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";

    private static Connection connection;

    private ConnectionManager() {}

    public static Connection getConnect() {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Теперь `ConnectionManager` управляет подключениями. Он гарантирует, что у вас будет 1 экземпляр `connection` на всех.
Использование в коде:

```
try(Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getConnect(); ...
```