# java apk Ошибка NullPointerException

Tags: java

при запуске приложения получаю ошибку:

```
02-08 19:47:41.997  6071  6071 D WakeMainActivity: [onCreate] begin
02-08 19:47:42.016  6071  6071 D WakeMainActivity: keyCode:0
02-08 19:47:42.016  6071  6071 D WakeGestureUtil: [isAppPresence] begin
02-08 19:47:42.017  6071  6071 D WakeSqliteManager: [SqliteManager]
02-08 19:47:42.017  6071  6071 D WakeSqliteManager: [queryAll]
02-08 19:47:42.018  6071  6071 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.wheatek.wakegesture, PID: 6071
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wheatek.wakegesture/com.wheatek.wakegesture.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wheatek.wakegesture.sqlite.SqliteManager.queryAll(SqliteManager.java:67)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wheatek.wakegesture.sqlite.SqliteManager.<init>(SqliteManager.java:21)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wheatek.wakegesture.util.GestureUtil.isAppPresence(GestureUtil.java:200)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wheatek.wakegesture.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637)
02-08 19:47:42.020  6071  6071 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
02-08 19:47:42.023   831  2882 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.wheatek.wakegesture/.MainActivity
02-08 19:47:42.029   831  2882 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.Settings$GestureSettingsActivity
```

выясил, что причиной является вот этот повторяющийся код

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.gestureSqliteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

в этом коде

```
package com.wheatek.wakegesture.sqlite;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import com.wheatek.wakegesture.R;
import com.wheatek.wakegesture.bean.KeyGestureFunction;
import com.wheatek.wakegesture.util.GestureUtil;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SqliteManager {
    private GestureSqliteOpenHelper gestureSqliteOpenHelper = new GestureSqliteOpenHelper(this.mContext);
    private Context mContext;

    public SqliteManager(Context context) {
        Log.d("WakeSqliteManager", "[SqliteManager]");
        this.mContext = context;
        if (queryAll() == null || queryAll().size() == 0) {
            initAllKey();
        }
    }

    public void addKEY(int key, String key_description, int type, String package_name, String apps_activity, String apps_name) {
        Log.d("WakeSqliteManager", "[addKEY] key_description:" + key_description);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.gestureSqliteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("insert into  gestureSettings(key,key_description,action_type,package_name,apps_activity,apps_name) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(key), key_description, Integer.valueOf(type), package_name, apps_activity, apps_name});
        db.close();
        Log.d("WakeSqliteManager", "[SqliteManager] end");
    }

    public String[] queryKey(int key) {
        Log.d("WakeSqliteManager", "[queryKey] key:" + key);
        String[] str_key = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.gestureSqliteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from  gestureSettings where key=?", new String[]{key + ""});
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                str_key = new String[]{cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("action_type")) + "", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("package_name")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("apps_activity"))};
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return str_key;
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return null;
    }

    public void updateKey(int key, int type, String package_name, String apps_activity, String apps_name) {
        Log.d("WakeSqliteManager", "[updateKey] apps_name:" + apps_name);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.gestureSqliteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("update gestureSettings set action_type=?, package_name=?,apps_activity=?,apps_name=?  where key=?", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(type), package_name, apps_activity, apps_name, Integer.valueOf(key)});
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(package_name)) {
            GestureUtil.setSwitchStatus(this.mContext, key, false);
        } else {
            GestureUtil.setSwitchStatus(this.mContext, key, true);
        }
        db.close();
        Log.d("WakeSqliteManager", "[updateKey] end");
    }

    public ArrayList<KeyGestureFunction> queryAll() {
        Log.d("WakeSqliteManager", "[queryAll]");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.gestureSqliteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from  gestureSettings ", new String[0]);
        ArrayList<KeyGestureFunction> keyGestureFunctions = new ArrayList();
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                keyGestureFunctions.add(new KeyGestureFunction(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("key")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("key_description")), cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("action_type")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("package_name")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("apps_activity")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("apps_name"))));
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return keyGestureFunctions;
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return null;
    }

    public void initAllKey() {
        Log.d("WakeSqliteManager", "[initAllKey] begin");
        Resources resources = this.mContext.getResources();
        boolean is_default_application = resources.getBoolean(R.bool.is_configuration_default_application);
        int[] default_gesture_switch = resources.getIntArray(R.array.default_gesture_switch);
        int[] key_int = resources.getIntArray(R.array.default_gesture_key);
        String[] default_Apps = resources.getStringArray(R.array.default_gesture_application);
        String[] key_decription = resources.getStringArray(R.array.array_gesture_letter);
        int i;
        String[] temp_pack;
        if (!is_default_application) {
            for (i = 0; i < key_int.length; i++) {
                addKEY(key_int[i], key_decription[i], -1, null, null, null);
                GestureUtil.setSwitchStatus(this.mContext, key_int[i], false);
            }
        } else if (this.mContext.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_function_gesture)) {
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                GestureUtil.setSwitchStatus(this.mContext, i, default_gesture_switch[i] == 1);
            }
            for (i = 4; i < key_int.length; i++) {
                temp_pack = default_Apps[i].split("_");
                if (temp_pack.length == 3) {
                    addKEY(key_int[i], key_decription[i], 2, temp_pack[1], temp_pack[2], temp_pack[0]);
                    GestureUtil.setSwitchStatus(this.mContext, key_int[i], true);
                }
            }
        } else {
            GestureUtil.setSwitchStatus(this.mContext, 34, default_gesture_switch[0] == 1);
            for (i = 0; i < key_int.length; i++) {
                temp_pack = default_Apps[i].split("_");
                if (temp_pack.length == 3) {
                    addKEY(key_int[i], key_decription[i], 2, temp_pack[1], temp_pack[2], temp_pack[0]);
                    GestureUtil.setSwitchStatus(this.mContext, key_int[i], true);
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("WakeSqliteManager", "[initAllKey] end");
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Переменная `mContext` определяется после инициализации объекта где она используется. Естественно, вы всегда будете получать NPE, т.к. она имеет `null` значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не учли порядок инициализации класса. Перед выполнением кода в конструкторе будет произведена инициализация полей класса. А в них у вас используется контекст, который всё ещё `null`, т.к. его присвоение в кострукторе ещё не произошло.

Т.е. вам надо перенести инициализацию поля `GestureSqliteOpenHelper gestureSqliteOpenHelper` в конструктор, сразу после инициализации требуемого для него контектса

```
public class SqliteManager {
    private GestureSqliteOpenHelper gestureSqliteOpenHelper;
    private Context mContext;

    public SqliteManager(Context context) {
        Log.d("WakeSqliteManager", "[SqliteManager]");
        mContext = context;
        gestureSqliteOpenHelper = new GestureSqliteOpenHelper(mContext);
```

Comment: очень умно написано, но я еще далек от этого (ибо только вичок в java). такие обазом я должен вырезать GestureSqliteOpenHelper из начала класса и вставить в метод SqliteManager? можно увидеть пример?

Comment: @vngreez, дополнил ответ

Comment: код работает исправно, необходимо ли создать новую тему для исправление других ошибок?

Comment: @vngreez, да, надо. Одна проблема - один вопрос