# Краш приложения на андроид android studio

Tags: java, android, listview

```
ListView listView1;

    String [] Title = {"one","two","four","five"};

    int[] imgid = {R.drawable.dela, R.drawable.gnev, R.drawable.psy};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();

        listView1.setAdapter(customAdapter);


        }


    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imgid.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.title,null);

            ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


            imageView2.setImageResource(imgid[i]);
            textView.setText(Title[i]);


            return view1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В логах пишет следующее  -  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.azot2, PID: 7738
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.azot2.ListActivity$CustomAdapter.getView(ListActivity.java:61)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш адаптер определён в классе активити, засим строка

> ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

расшифровывается компилятором в

```
ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)ActivityClassName.this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

т.е. вы ищите `ImageView` в разметке активити, а не разметке элемента списка. Так происходит потому, что компилятор видит метод `findViewById` и сначала пытается его найти в классе адаптера. Но у него такого метода нет. Засим компилятор ищет в обрамляющем классе этот метод. Находит его, вызывает на экземпляре этого класса, но вьюху там не находит, она становится `null`, после чего вы и получаете `NPE`. Вы бы избежали этого, если бы описали ваш адаптер в отдельном классе, как и следует делать, если вы пишите реальное приложение, а не разбираете пример.

Вам надо искать вашу вьюху в разметке элемента списка, вызывая метод на ней так:

```
ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

---

Также, советую переходить на `RecyclerView` -  современную версию `ListView`.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь все работает

Comment: ViewHolder всего лишь кэширует ссылки на виджеты (хранит значение, полученное методом `findViewById()`) и никаким образом не решает проблемы мешанины в элементах списка при скролле

Comment: @pavlofff, ну, в главном то я прав) Исправил)