# Как правильно вызвать Permission на работу с геолокацией?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Всем добрый день, в момент когда запрашиваю у пользователя разрешение на работу с геолокацией, приложение прекращает работу.

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }else{
            setCurrentGeo();
        }
     }
```

Вот что пишет LogCat

> 06-19 12:30:04.284 20047-20047/popovvad.findme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: popovvad.findme, PID: 20047
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{popovvad.findme/popovvad.findme.MapActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView.onStart()' on a null object
>   reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView.onStart()' on a
>   null object reference
>           at popovvad.findme.MapActivity.onStart(MapActivity.java:121)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
>           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7029)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)  06-19
>   12:30:04.316 20047-20085/popovvad.findme
>   E/com.yandex.runtime.sensors.internal.LastKnownLocation: failed to get
>   last known location: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location
>   provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

Крашится на строчке с условием

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

При этом если разрешение на геолокацию есть, то приложение идет дальше как положено и работает исправно, вот и возник вопрос как правильно вызвать диалог permission в этом случае ? Ещё на заметку, после того как приложение завершило роботу, появляется диалог на разрешение работы приложения с геолокацией.

Разрешения в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Крэшится вот где: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView.onStart()' on a null object reference at popovvad.findme.MapActivity.onStart(MapActivity.java:121)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Нет, дело в том что диалог permission вызывается в рантайме, моя ошибка заключалась в том что я одновременно запрашивал координаты у провайдера и разрешение на работу с геолокацией у пользователя. NullPointerException тут не причем.

Comment: Так потому и NullPointerException, если он есть, он всегда причем.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja проблема в неверной архитектуре приложения, всё поправил как написал в ответе, спасибо за отзывчивость)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Принял для себя следующее решение, разрешение на работу с геолокацией вызываю в самом начале работы приложения, т.к. это разрешение для меня является ключевым объектом. Тем самым на момент когда вызываю запрос координат у провайдера уже имею разрешение на работу с геолокацией.

[Хорошая статья на эту тему](https://habr.com/post/278945/)

> Если функция критична и без нее программа не будет иметь смысла, то смело просите разрешения прямо при запуске приложения

Comment: У вас был явно нарушен альтернативный путь инициализации (когда запрашиваете разрешение пользователя), поэтому все и падало. А когда запрашивать, не суть важно.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja тем не менее, проблема решилась, спасибо