# Ошибка при запуске Android приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пытаюсь сделать простое приложение для работы с  wifi сетями, одной из частей которого должен быть сканер wifi сетей. Изначально сделал также, как было отвечено здесь:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452940/how-can-i-get-android-wifi-scan-results-into-a-list

Данный код успешно работал на моем тестовом устройстве. Далее решил отделить функционал сканирования от "основного" и вынести все элементы интерфейса в Main. После чего на том же самом тестовом устройстве приложение начало падать с выводом: "приложение wifi_demo.xml остановлено". В андроиде новичок, никак не могу выяснить, что сделал не так.

Лог об ошибке:

```
   08-20 13:11:40.216 18683-18683/com.example.lazm.helloapp I/System.out: debugger has settled (1466)
   08-20 13:11:40.236 18683-18683/com.example.lazm.helloapp I/PersonaManager: getPersonaService() name persona_policy
   08-20 13:11:40.436 18683-18683/com.example.lazm.helloapp D/AbsListView:   Get MotionRecognitionManager
   08-20 13:11:40.457 18683-18683/com.example.lazm.helloapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
   08-20 13:11:40.457 18683-18683/com.example.lazm.helloapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418abda0)
   08-20 13:11:40.467 18683-18683/com.example.lazm.helloapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lazm.helloapp, PID: 18683
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lazm.helloapp/com.example.lazm.helloapp.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
          at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:486)
          at com.example.lazm.helloapp.Main.onCreate(Main.java:37)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Код:

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    ListView lv;
    TextView textStatus;
    Button buttonScan;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    private String ITEM_KEY = "key";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wifi_demo);

        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new         
String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { R.id.list_value });
        lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        arraylist.clear();
        WiFiDemo demo = new WiFiDemo(this);
        arraylist = demo.getNetworksList();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

WiFiDemo.java:

```
public class WiFiDemo 
{
    private Context context;
    private WifiManager wifi;
    private int size = 0;
    private List<ScanResult> results;

    private String ITEM_KEY = "key";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new     
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public WiFiDemo()
    {

    }

    public WiFiDemo(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        wifi = (WifiManager)      
this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        this.context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
            {
                results.clear();
                results = wifi.getScanResults();
                size = results.size();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getNetworksList()
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = new 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        if (!wifi.isWifiEnabled())
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Activating WiFi", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        wifi.startScan();

        // Wait for broadcast reply

        getNetworksFromBroadcastReply();

        return arraylist;
    }

    private void getNetworksFromBroadcastReply()
    {
        arraylist.clear();

        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Scanned: [" + size + "] networks 
available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try
        {
            size = size - 1;
            while (size >= 0)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID + "  " + 
results.get(size).capabilities);

                arraylist.add(item);
                size--;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Scan error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

wifi_demo.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textStatus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Status" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonScan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Scan" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Файл манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lazm.helloapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="wifi_demo.xml"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.lazm.helloapp.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: почему не удалось получить стектрейс? если приложение аварийно остановлено, в логкат будет подробный лог о ошибке в любом случае. Без лога ошибки это гадание на кофейной гуще, мало кто таким любит заниматься

Comment: Все таки смог найти лог, правда он не очень продвинул меня в понимании причины. Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Ошибка в 37-й строке `Main.java` - научитесь хотя бы логи читать что ли...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в адаптер `arraylist` передаёте:

```
this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { R.id.list_value });
```

Но `arraylist` не проинициализировали, там `null`.

В `SimpleAdapter` у вас где-то в коде берётся `arraylist.count()`, и оно падает.