# java.lang.NullPointerException, как исправить и в чём суть проблемы?

Tags: java, eclipse

Делаю графический калькулятор со слайдерами для ввода значений коэффициентов функций. Eclipse ни в какую не запускает и не компилирует код,а в консоли выдаёт java.lang.NullPointerException. Как это исправить и в чём суть ошибки?
вот код:

```
package pack;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class GDC {

    private JFrame frame;
    private double h=0;
    private double k=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GDC window = new GDC();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public GDC() {
        initialize();
    }


    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 550, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.setBounds(10, 38, 300, 300);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);

        JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        slider.setValue(0);
        slider.setMinimum(-100);

        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

                h= slider.getValue(); 
                k = slider.getValue();
                Graphics g =canvas.getGraphics();

                canvas.update(g);
                g.setColor(Color.black);

                g.drawLine(0,canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()/2);
                g.drawLine(canvas.getWidth()/2,0, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight());            

                double y1=0;
                double y2=0;

                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.translate(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);

                for (double x =-300; x<301 ; x++)
                {
                    y1= Math.pow(x-h, 2)+k;
                    y2= Math.pow(x+1-h, 2)+k;

                    g.drawLine((int)x, (int) -y1, (int)x+1, (int) -y2);

                }
            }
        });
        slider.setBounds(325, 40, 200, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(slider);

        JLabel lblInputBValue = new JLabel("Input k value");
        lblInputBValue.setBounds(385, 15, 77, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblInputBValue);

        JLabel lblYaxkp = new JLabel("y=a(x-h)+k");
        lblYaxkp.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 25));
        lblYaxkp.setBounds(23, 3, 151, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblYaxkp);

        JSlider slider_1 = new JSlider();
        slider_1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {

                h= slider.getValue();
                k = slider.getValue();
                Graphics g =canvas.getGraphics();

                canvas.update(g);
                g.setColor(Color.black);

                g.drawLine(0,canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()/2);
                g.drawLine(canvas.getWidth()/2,0, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight());            

                double y1=0;
                double y2=0;

                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.translate(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);

                for (double x =-300; x<301 ; x++)
                {
                    y1= Math.pow(x-h,2)+k;
                    y2= Math.pow(x+1-h,2)+k;

                    g.drawLine((int)x, (int) -y1, (int)x+1, (int) -y2);

                }


            }
                }); 
        slider_1.setValue(0);
        slider_1.setMinimum(-100);
        slider_1.setBounds(325, 127, 200, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(slider_1);

        JSlider slider_2 = new JSlider();
        slider_2.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            }
        });
        slider_2.setValue(0);
        slider_2.setMinimum(-100);
        slider_2.setBounds(325, 226, 200, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(slider_2);

        JLabel lblInputKValue = new JLabel("Input h value");
        lblInputKValue.setBounds(385, 102, 77, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblInputKValue);

        JLabel lblInputAValue = new JLabel("Input a value");
        lblInputAValue.setBounds(385, 201, 77, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblInputAValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511085/204271)

Comment: На какой строчке ошибка?

Comment: проблема решена,всем огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте среднюю строчку:

```
            Graphics g = canvas.getGraphics();
            if (g == null) return;
            canvas.update(g);
```