# Что необходимо сделать чтобы hibernate установил соединение с БД mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, intellij-idea

При выполнение учебного задания возникла проблема. Hibernate не может подключиться к БД, логин и пароль правильные. При написание в идеи скрипта SELECT * FROM test.parts_list, таблица выводится. В чем заключается моя ошибка?

```
import model.CompDetail;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Test2 {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Test2() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(CompDetail.class);
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new 
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = 
                        configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());


        }
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property 
name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property 
name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test/</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">12345</property>
        <property 
name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Ошибка:

```
мая 21, 2019 11:36:46 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.1.Final}
мая 21, 2019 11:36:47 PM 
org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager 
<clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
мая 21, 2019 11:36:47 PM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for 
production use!)
мая 21, 2019 11:36:47 PM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL 
[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test/]
мая 21, 2019 11:36:47 PM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
мая 21, 2019 11:36:47 PM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
мая 21, 2019 11:36:47 PM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
мая 21, 2019 11:36:47 PM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator 
initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
мая 21, 2019 11:36:47 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
мая 21, 2019 11:36:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 
logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
мая 21, 2019 11:36:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 
logExceptions
ERROR: Could not create connection to database server.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: 
Unable to create requested service 
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl
.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at 
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl
.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl
.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
at 
org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory
.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl
.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl
.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl
.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl
.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess
.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess
.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl
.build(MetadataBuilderImpl
.java:473)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl
.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
at Test2.main(Test2.java:19)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception
.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
at org.hibernate.exception.internal
.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal
.StandardSQLExceptionConverter
.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException
(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
 .DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections
 .addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:321)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
 .DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>    
 (DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:240)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
 .DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>    
 (DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:218)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
 .DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder
 .build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:359)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
 .DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
 .buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
 .DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
 .configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal
 .StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl
 .java:107)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal
 .AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService
 (AbstractServiceRegistryImpl
 .java:246)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl
 .getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator
 .buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal
.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService
(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator
.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl
.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl
.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
... 13 more
Caused by:     
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
 Could not create connection to database server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:958)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
at   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl
.java:2326)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2079)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl
.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal
.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at     com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2999)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1885)
at     
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO
.java:1814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1207)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2249)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly
(ConnectionImpl.java:2280)
... 39 more
```

Мавен:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

драйвер: MySql for 5.1

Comment: Код нужно выложить здесь, причем не весь, а только [часть, относящуюся к ошибке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). Сообщение об ошибке нужно выложить текстом, а не картинкой. Как исправить это исключение читаем здесь: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511085)

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить `findById(...)` будет ли у него ошибка

Comment: @defaultlocale . Добрый день. Спасибо за указанные недостатки, устранил. Выложил все классы, т.к. считаю, что где-то ,возможно, есть ошибка. Картинку,к сожалению, пока-что убрать не могу. Проблема, если я понимаю правильно, в подключении хибернета к БД, за счет чего программа бросает NullPointerException. Прошу Вас посмотреть еще раз данную проблему и поделиться опытом устранения проблемы.

Comment: Попробуйте без всяких сервисов и дао, просто в методе main выполнить логику которая у вас присутствует в методе CompDetailDao::findAll

Comment: Сюдя по ошибке в логах, у вас неправильно настроено подключение к бд

Comment: @Rumeet94 Стало лучше, но кода все-таким многовато. Исключение у Вас выпадает в `HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory()` т.ч. лучше скопировать код этого метода в `Main` после чего оставить только `Main`, а остальной код убрать. Еще уберите `try/catch` из этого метода: Вы выводите только тип и сообщение об ошибке, а хотелось бы увидеть полную трассировку исключения.

Comment: @Rumeet94 А пока выстрел наудачу: попробуйте заменить `url` на `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test`

Comment: @defaultlocale Добрый вечер, сделал все, как вы рекомендовали. Лог и код обновил и перекрепил. jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test не прошло. Прошу Вашей помощи

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Здравствуйте. Спасибо за отклик. Попробовал, не получилось. Прикрепил выше рекомендации defaultlocal (отдельно код и лог). Прошу Вашей помощи, посмотреть и, возможно, найти ошибку

Comment: @Rumeet94 Уже теплее! Поискал информацию по Вашей ошибке. Люди предлагают [обновить версию драйвера до последней](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137173/exception-in-connection-with-mysql-through-jdbc). Попробуйте обновить. Если не получится, то укажите в вопросе версию драйвера, а если используете maven то и весь POM.xml

Comment: @defaultlocale добавил, что Вы сказали. Обновил зависимости как было в вашей ссылки, не помогло...

Comment: @Rumeet94 Очень жаль, я вариантов пока не вижу. В другом ответе предлагают в connection url проставить кодировку `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true`.  Попробуйте, вдруг поможет. Еще, проверьте [версию MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987679/how-to-retrieve-the-current-version-of-a-mysql-database) и укажите ее в вопросе. Позже попробую воспроизвести ошибку. Если что-нибудь найду, то напишу здесь.

Comment: Еще, проверьте видит ли Hibernate конфигурацию. Добавьте `System.out.println(configuration.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"))` после `Configuration().configure();`. Если выведет URL из файла, то надо будет попробовать воспроизвести проблему без hibernate на JDBC. Если выведет что-то другое, то нужно будет показать где лежит hibernate.cfg.xml.