# Параметр из JavaFX не работает в таймере из Swing

Tags: java, javafx

```
public class Main extends Application {
private Stage stage;
private Scene scene;
private AnchorPane loading;
public Timer timer;
public int timerV, stageV;
Menu m = new Menu();

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
    loading = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("res/1 loading/paw.fxml"));
    scene = new Scene(loading);
    this.stage = stage;
    stage.setY(225);
    stage.setX(430);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    timer  = new Timer(1000, null);
    timer.start();
    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            timerV++;
            if(timerV==15){
                m.stage.show();
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    });
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}
Надеюсь, смысл понятен. Тут просто запускается одна сцена после другой, но как в том-то и проблема, что она не запускается... Почему-то все параметры из JFX(a) не работают внутри таймера из Swing(a). Вот, что пишет консоль:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:35)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:317)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:249)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-null-pointer-exception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: У вас все ошибки идут из java awt. У вас точно все импорты правильные ?