# Не могу понять почему выводит ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

```
public JSONArray longPoll() {
    JSONObject response;
    JSONObject data = this.longPoll;

    
    do {
        String Url = String.format(
                "{$server}?act=a_check&key={$key}&ts={$ts}&wait=25 ",
                data.get("server"), data.get("key"), data.get("ts") );// <-- это 46 cтрока
        response = VKLib.parse(Url);

        if(response.containsKey("error")) {
            this.setLongPoll();
        }
    
    } while(response.containsKey("error"));
    
    data.put("ts", response.get("ts"));
    
    JSONArray updates = (response.containsKey("updates")) ? 
            (JSONArray) response.get("updates") :
            null;
    
    return updates;
}
```

показывает такую ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at vk.Vk.longPoll(Vk.java:46)
```

Comment: Выложите весь код

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511085/204271)

Comment: на какой итерации вылетает ошибка?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)