# Метод remove в LinkedList

Tags: java

При удалении элемента со списка с индексом 0 генерируется исключение, нужна помощь в исправлении кода метода remove.

```
        @Override
public E remove(int index) {
    if (size > 0) {
        checkIndexAndSize(index);
        Node<E> node;
        node = firstNode.next;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            node = node.next;
        }

        if (size > 1) {
            node.prev.next = node.next;
            node.next.prev = node.prev;
        }
        size--;
        return node.currentElement;
    }
    throw new NegativeArraySizeException("The list is empty, deletion is impossible");
}
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: предлагаете угадать, что за ислючение? И остальной код для воспроизведения проблемы вообразить?

Comment: Не думаю что тут уместен весь код, а исключение NullPointerException

Comment: Как вы можете знать, что уместно, а что нет, если вы не справились сами со своей проблемой. Ок, я не буду спорить, вам видней. Я просто дам тогла вам пару ссылок - дальше сами. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511086/179763)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Добавил, но там ничего полезного особо и нету

Comment: @Slavuuhhaaa, есть же. Видно в какой строке ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, при удалении нулевого элемента нужно менять ссылку не у предыдущего а у первого листа, в итоге получится:

```
        @Override
public E remove(int index) {
    if (size > 0 && index - 1 < size) {
        Node<E> node = firstNode.next;
        checkIndexAndSize(index);
        if (index == 0) {
            firstNode.next=node.next;
            node.next.prev=firstNode;
        } else if (index > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                node = node.next;
            }
            if (size > 1) {
                node.prev.next = node.next;
                node.next.prev = node.prev;

            }
        }

        size--;
        return node.currentElement;
    }
    throw new NegativeArraySizeException("The list is empty, deletion is impossible");
}
```