# не работает итератор в hashmap

Tags: java, generics, итераторы, hashmap

Дали задание написать простой HashMap c тестами

public class SimpleHashMap<K,V> implements Iterable
параметризован T почему то не показывает

```
 private T[] array;
    private int load;
    private int modCount;
    private int size;

    public SimpleHashMap() {
        this.array = new T[16];
        load = (int) (array.length * 0.75);
    }

    public boolean insert(K key, V value) {
        boolean result = false;
        int index = -1;
        T temp = new T(key, value);
        index = hash(key);
        if (size + 1 >= load) {
            load *= 2;
            expensive();
        }
        if (array[index] == null) {
            array[index] = temp;
            result = true;
            size++;
            modCount++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    private void expensive() {
      T[] temp = array;
      array = new T[temp.length * 2];
      size = 0;
      for (T tmp : temp) {
          if (tmp != null) {
              insert((K)tmp.getKey(), (V)tmp.getValue());
          }
      }
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return (V) array[hash(key)].getValue();
    }

    public boolean delete(K key) {
       boolean result = false;
       if (array[hash(key)] != null) {
           array[hash(key)] = null;
           size--;
           modCount++;
           result = true;
       }
       return result;
    }

    public int hash(K key) {
       int temp = 31;
        temp = temp * 17 + key.hashCode();
        return temp % array.length;
    }


    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            private  int expectedModCount = modCount;
            private int position = 0;
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return position < size;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                } else if (expectedModCount != modCount) {
                    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
                }
                return array[position++];
            }
        };
    }

и тест 

  @Test
        public void whenCreateIteratorThen() {
        SimpleHashMap<Integer, String> map = new SimpleHashMap<>();
        map.insert(12, "one");
        map.insert(1, "two");
        Iterator<T> it = map.iterator();
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        assertThat(it.next().getKey(), is(1));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(true));
        System.out.println(it.hasNext());
        assertThat(it.next().getKey(), is(12));
        assertThat(it.hasNext(), is(false));
    }
```

не пойму почему не работает итератор кидает NullPointerexception

.  почему то не хочет показывать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю тот ли это ответ который ожидается, но попробую.
Нельзя "напрямую" создавать массив дженериков, соответственно строка:
`this.array = new T[16];` абсолютно некорректна, её можно заменить на что-то вроде:
`this.array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 16);`, где `clazz` - класс, для типа `T`, переданный в конструктор или ещё как-то. Вот [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generic-array) подробнее.

> public class SimpleHashMap<K,V> implements Iterable
> параметризован T

Если я правильно понял, то это значит:

```java
public class SimpleHashMap<K,V> implements Iterable<T> {
```

Так тоже делать нельзя, т.к. `Т` нигде предварительно заявлен не был. Если особо в код не лезть, то можно сделать так (я понимаю, что это не соответствует заданию, зато очень наглядно):

```java
public class SimpleHashMap<K,V,T> implements Iterable<T> {
```

Я бы посоветовал хранить значения не в массиве, а в списке. Что-то вида `List<Pair<K,V>>`, где `Pair` внутренний класс, который содежрит ключ-значение. Можно даже не список, а set. Не придётся самому думать про его размер. Если это не вариант, тогда хранить эти пары в массиве `Pair<K,V>`, или два массива: один под ключ, другой под значение.
Также не не корректна эта строка:

```java
insert((K)tmp.getKey(), (V)tmp.getValue());
```

Откуда берутся эти два метода? Компилятор про них ничего не знает. Чтобы он про них что-то знал, можно сделать что-то вида (что также не соответствует заданию):

```java
public class SimpleHashMap<K extends Getable, V extends Getable,T> implements Iterable<T> {
```

где `Getable` интерфейс с поддержкой метода `get()`.

Answer (score 1):

Должна вам сказать, в мапе не используется `Iterable` - в ней принципиально другой способ хранения данных.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете убедиться в этом, заглянув в исходники. Для того, чтобы определить, куда запихнуть пару, у ключа не вычисляется заново хеш - он берется сразу методом `hashCode()`, поэтому хешмапа такая и быстрая. Она представляет из себя ассоциативный массив, вовсе не список.

При вычислении хешкода объекта случаются коллизии, когда хешкод совпадает, и тогда значения помещаются на тот же индекс в односвязный список - пока не достигнут какого-то максимума, например, в 8 элементов. После преодоления этой цифры список превращается в черно-белое дерево, чтобы поиск происходил быстрее.

Тоесть: вы просите мапу выдать вам значение по ключу - она смотрит и видит, что у нее там несколько значений, она берет ваш ключ и ходит по односвязному списку и сравнивает каждое значение, поэтому для хранения каких-то объектов в них обязательно должны быть переопределены методы `equals()` и `hashCode()`

Черное-белое дерево же нужно для того, чтобы, когда список станет слишком большим, поиск можно было осуществить с помощью алгоритма типа "разделяй и властвуй". Но, как правило, такого не происходит, если хеш-коды у объектов определены хорошо.

Но кстати, насчет того на какой индекс запихивать элемент - зависит от реализации. Так же, `HashSet` в java использует под капотом мапу, только значения у нее null

Исходя из все вышесказанного, я бы на вашем месте переписала половину, наверняка, ваше решение будет rejected

Можете добавить node и уже из него пилить массив:

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
        final int hash;
        final K key;
        V value;
        Node<K,V> next;

        Node(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {
            this.hash = hash;
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public final K getKey()        { return key; }
        public final V getValue()      { return value; }
        public final String toString() { return key + "=" + value; }

        public final int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hashCode(key) ^ Objects.hashCode(value);
        }

        public final V setValue(V newValue) {
            V oldValue = value;
            value = newValue;
            return oldValue;
        }

        public final boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o == this)
                return true;
            if (o instanceof Map.Entry) {
                Map.Entry<?,?> e = (Map.Entry<?,?>)o;
                if (Objects.equals(key, e.getKey()) &&
                    Objects.equals(value, e.getValue()))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

========================

Node<K,V>[] table;

(p.s. from HashMap docs)
```

А насчет итератора - его можно будет поотдельности добавить в `ValueSet/KeySet`