# Написал код для записи из одного excel файла в другой. Выдает ошибку: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Try5.Main5.ma..."

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi

Написал код для записи из одного excel файла в другой. Выдает ошибку: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Try5.Main5.main(Main5.java:30)"

Не могу понять причину. Вот код:

```
package Try5;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class Main5 {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\egorovvv\\Documents\\IntelIJ IDEA\\Projects\\Work Excel 2\\Excel1.xlsx");
        FileOutputStream fos3 = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\egorovvv\\Documents\\IntelIJ IDEA\\Projects\\Work Excel 2\\Excel3.xlsx");
        Workbook book1 = new XSSFWorkbook(fis1);
        Workbook book3 = new XSSFWorkbook();
        String value;
        int bookSN = book1.getNumberOfSheets(); //bookSheetsNumber
        for (int i = 0; i <= bookSN; i++) {
            Sheet book1S = book1.getSheetAt(i);
            int book1RN = book1S.getLastRowNum(); //book1RowsNumber
            Sheet book3S = book3.createSheet(book1.getSheetName(i));
            for (int j = 0; j <= book1RN; j++) {
                Row book1R = book1S.getRow(j);
                int book1CN = book1R.getLastCellNum(); //book1CellsNumber
                Row book3R = book3S.createRow(j);
                for (int k = 0; k <= book1CN; k++) {
                    Cell book1C = book1R.getCell(k);
                    Cell book3C = book3R.createCell(k);
                    switch (book1C.getCellType()) {
                        case NUMERIC:
                            value = Integer.toString((int)book1C.getNumericCellValue());
                            book3C.setCellValue(value);
                            break;
                        case STRING:
                            value = book1C.getStringCellValue();
                            book3C.setCellValue(value);
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        book3.write(fos3);
        book1.close();
        book3.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил условный оператор switch. Теперь все работает. Код ниже:

```
package Try6;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class Main6 {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\egorovvv\\Documents\\IntelIJ IDEA\\Projects\\Work Excel 2\\book1.xlsx");
        FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\egorovvv\\Documents\\IntelIJ IDEA\\Projects\\Work Excel 2\\book3.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook b1 = new XSSFWorkbook(fis1);
        XSSFWorkbook b3 = new XSSFWorkbook();
        int b1SN = b1.getNumberOfSheets();
        int b1RN;
        int b1CN;
        String valueString = "0";
        int valueInt = 0;

        for (int sh = 0; sh < b1SN; sh++) {
            Sheet b1S = b1.getSheetAt(sh);
            Sheet b3S = b3.createSheet(b1S.getSheetName());
            b1RN = b1S.getLastRowNum();

            for (int r = 0; r <= b1RN; r++) {
                Row b1R = b1S.getRow(r);
                Row b3R = b3S.createRow(r);
                b1CN = b1R.getLastCellNum();

                for (int c = 0; c <= b1CN; c++) {
                    Cell b1C = b1R.getCell(c);
                    Cell b3C = b3R.createCell(c);

                    if (b1C != null) {
                        switch (b1C.getCellType()) {
                            case NUMERIC:
                                valueInt = (int) b1C.getNumericCellValue();
                                b3C.setCellValue(valueInt);
                                break;
                            case STRING:
                                valueString = b1C.getStringCellValue();
                                b3C.setCellValue(valueString);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
//                    if (r == 0 && c == 0 || c == 1 || c == 3 || c == 4 || c == 5 || c == 6 || c == 7 || c == 8) {
//                        CellRangeAddress mergeCells = new CellRangeAddress(0,1,0,0);
//                        b3S.addMergedRegion(mergeCells);
//                    }
                }
            }
        }
        b3.write(fos1);
        fos1.close();
    }
}
```