# Как получить столбец X и перебрать все его строки?

Tags: java, excel, jsoup

Есть общедоступная таблица MicrosoftExcel Online.
Мне нужно перебрать все строки (от 1 и до N) столбца X и вывести их содержание.
Трудность в том, что я не могу сообразить, как именно итерировать строки по столбцу.
В документации, к сожалению, полезного для себя не подчерпнул. Направьте на правильный путь, пожалуйста.

[image: столбец Х]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте взять из этого решения.
По сути это простой цикл внутри цикла внутри цикла:

Файл File
Лист Sheet
Строки Row
Ячейки Cell

на каждом этапе пользуйтесь методом .get Sheet/Row/Cell

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1318711/457068