# Apache Tomcat выдаёт исключение - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, tomcat, jira

Я новичок в Java EE и т.д., поэтому заранее прощу прощения если вопрос дурацкий, но я уже третий день не могу понять, что не так. В общем не могу понять по какой причине возникает исключение - java.lang.NullPointerException.

Я пишу небольшую программу, которая немного автоматизирует процесс. Сама идея:

Есть инстанс Jira Service desk v. 7.3.3, как известно у неё есть встроенный Tomcat, на котором она работает, так вот я хочу, чтобы мой Servlet, помещённый в папку /opt/atlassian/jira/webapps умел считывать данные из файлов - xls, xlsx, которые JIRA хранит как вложения в директории /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/data/attachments/project-key/issue-key и далее работать с этими данными.

Сами исходники можно клонировать отсюда - git clone https://GusMen@bitbucket.org/GusMen/xls.git

Чтобы иметь возможность читать xls файлы я использую в Java библиотеку Apache POI.

На локалке servlet работает просто отлично.

Например файл сохранён в директории E:\test.xls из Inteliij idea запустил Tomcat
[image: localhost]

Данные считываются и печатаются, но на удалённом же сервере выпадает исключение

[image: Remote Tomcat]

В чём ошибка понять никак не могу, пробовал разное.

1. Думал, что проблема в доступе к файлу, но например к txt файлам я могу достучаться и прочитать их.
2. Подумал, что проблема в правах, сделал права chmod 777, не помогло

В общем буду рад любой помощи. Заранее Спасибо!

Servlet

```
package com.example.read_excel_file;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.example.read_excel_file.classes.readTheAttachment;

@WebServlet(name = "MainServlet", value = "/autoRs25")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String fileName, list;
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        list = request.getParameter("list");

        readTheAttachment readTheAttachment = new readTheAttachment();
        Map<String, String> rs25 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        rs25 = readTheAttachment.fileReader(fileName, list);
        writer.println("<code>");
        writer.println(rs25);
        writer.println("</code>");
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Вспомогательный класс

```
package com.example.read_excel_file.classes;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class readTheAttachment {
    public Map<String, String> fileReader(String fileName, String list) {
        Map<String, String> rs25 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String filial = null;
        String userName = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;

        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(list);
        Iterator<Row> it = sheet.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Row row = it.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.iterator();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cells.next();
                int cellType = cell.getCellType();
                switch (cellType) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        if (filial != null) {
                            userName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        } else {
                            filial = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("error");
                        break;
                }
            }
            rs25.put(filial, userName);
            filial = null;
            userName = null;
        }
        return rs25;
    }
}
```

Comment: есть же стэктрейс, посмотрите и попробуйте понять где выскакивает NPE , не получается, приведите кусок кода, опытный человек мельком взглянув сможет вам подсказать, а лезть в исходники , я думаю вряд ли кто будет этим заниматься.

Comment: Вместо затянутого вступления и общего описания проекта имело смысл представить конкретный фрагмент кода.  См. [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AlexRudenko код в описании.

Comment: @стасевич спасибо за подсказку, к сожалению я в Java новичок, с этим ещё не встречался. Почитаю

Comment: если вы новичок в java, то зачем браться за ЕЕ? осваивайте SE , и уже потом беритесь за enterprise

Comment: @стасевич Появилась необходимость хотя бы вникнуть в enterprise, поскольку дали задание на работе

Comment: Здесь скорей всего причина в том, что было перехвачено и распечатано исключение при попытке доступа к файлу, после чего `workbook` остался `null` и при последующем обращении `Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(list);` вылетело NPE.  Надо проверять логи сервера на предмет вывода `IOException` в строке `System.out.println(exception);`, а ещё лучше пробросить это исключение дальше, например обернув его в RuntimeException

Comment: В целом сама идея доступа к файловой системе на стороне веб-сервера, да ещё и с `chmod 777` "абы работало" выглядит небезопасной.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)