# Ошибка: Cannot invoke because "levels[i]" is null

Tags: java

я пишу метод, который создает объект "house", в нём есть массив этажей, на каждом этаже массив квартир. При присвоении номера квартире выскакивает такая ошибка, не могу разобраться почему? (Ошибка кроется в первых строках цикла, поэтому полный коне стал давать т.к там похожие операции и такие же ошибки)

**Класс Level**

```java
public class Level {
    private int number;
    private Flat[] flats;

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
```

**Класс HouseRun**

```java
public class HouseRun {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectCreating(5,4);
        }
        
       public static void ObjectCreating(int HouseNumber, int LevelsQuantities){
           int  FlatsCount = 1;
           House house = new House(HouseNumber, LevelsQuantities);
           Level[] levels = new Level[LevelsQuantities];
           for (int i = 0; i < levels.length ; i++) {
               levels[i].setNumber(i+1);
               levels[i].setFlats();
               Flat[] levelsFlats = levels[i].getFlats();
```

Comment: Какие-то совсем обрезанные участки кода, хорошо хоть по ним можно найти ошибку. Вы создаете массив объектов Level[] levels, но самих объектов в нем нет т.к. вы их не создали и не поместили в этот массив. Сами по себе они не создадутся.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это типичная ошибка полагать, что при создании массива создаётся массив с "пустыми" объектами.  На самом деле, массивы заполняются `null`-ами, и перед вызовом каких-либо методов экземпляра класса `Level`, нужно этот экземпляр создать, вызвав какой-либо конструктор (хотя бы конструктор без аргументов, существующий по умолчанию).

```java
Level[] levels = new Level[LevelsQuantities];
for (int i = 0; i < levels.length ; i++) {
    levels[i] = new Level(); // создать экземпляр Level в массиве!
    levels[i].setNumber(i + 1);
    levels[i].setFlats();
    Flat[] levelsFlats = levels[i].getFlats();
}
```