# java collections

Tags: java

Нужно положить в коллекцию объект, который имеет имя (name) и координаты (x, y).

Элементы, хранимые в коллекции, описываются в классе Product

```
public class Product {
String name;
Coordinates coordinates;

Product() {
}

Product(String name, Coordinates coordinates) {
    this.name = name;
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", coordinates=" + coordinates.getX() +" "+
            coordinates.getY()+
            '}';
}
```

}
Координаты x и y описываются в классе Coordinates

```
public class Coordinates {
int x;
int y;

Coordinates(int x, int y){
    this.y=y;
    this.x = x;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Coordinates{" +
            "x=" + x +
            ", y=" + y +
            '}';
}
```

}`
В классе Main осуществляется заполнение коллекции

```
public class Main {
public static  void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Product> list= new ArrayList<>();
    Product product = new Product();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name:");
    product.name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter x:");
    product.coordinates.x = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter y:");
    product.coordinates.y = scanner.nextInt();
    list.add(product);
    System.out.println(product);

}
```

}
Проблема заключается в том, что координаты добавить получается, но вывести их нет, выходит ошибка NullPointerException конкретно в этом фрагменте

```
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", coordinates=" + coordinates.getX() +" "+
            coordinates.getY()+
            '}';
}
```

В чем заключается проблема ?

Comment: кроме инициализации поля coordinates, хорошей практикой будет использовать сделанные геттеры и сеттеры

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете конструктор без параметров, в котором ничего не делается. И все поля у вас не проинициализированы.

`product.coordinates` окажется null после использования  `Product product = new Product();`