# Ошибка NullpointerExpectuon

Tags: java, android, отладка

Ошибка

```
Process: forsaj.app, PID: 15019
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at forsaj.app.ui.ZayavkiClientActivity$1.onBindViewHolder(ZayavkiClientActivity.java:53)
        at forsaj.app.ui.ZayavkiClientActivity$1.onBindViewHolder(ZayavkiClientActivity.java:50)
```

Проблемный метод

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<OtvetShop> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<OtvetShop>()
                .setQuery(ZayavkaRef, OtvetShop.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<OtvetShop, OtvetShopHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<OtvetShop, OtvetShopHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder( @androidx.annotation.NonNull OtvetShopHolder holder, int position,  @androidx.annotation.NonNull OtvetShop model) {
                holder.txt_tovarname.setText(model.getTovarname());
                holder.txt_tovarprice.setText(model.getTovarprice());
               holder.txt_shopadress.setText(model.getMagazadress());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.image_tovar_shop);
            }

            @Override
            public OtvetShopHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_shop,parent,false);
          OtvetShopHolder holder=new OtvetShopHolder(view);


                return holder;
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

OtvetShopHolder

```
    public ItemShopClickLIstner lIstner;
    public TextView txt_tovarname,txt_tovarprice,txt_shopadress;
public ImageView image_tovar_shop;
public AppCompatButton button_no_shop,button_yes_shop;

    public OtvetShopHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        txt_shopadress=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_shop_adress);
        txt_tovarname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_tovar_name);
        txt_tovarprice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_tovar_price);
        image_tovar_shop=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_tovar_shop);
image_tovar_shop=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_tovar_shop);



    }
    public void setItemShopClickListner(ItemShopClickLIstner listner){this.lIstner=listner;}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        lIstner.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }
}
```

OtvetShop(Adapter)

```
public class OtvetShop {
    private String tovarname,tovarprice,magazadress,productId,date,time,image;
   public OtvetShop(){

    }

    public OtvetShop(String tovarname, String tovarprice, String magazadress, String productId, String date, String time, String image) {
        this.tovarname = tovarname;
        this.tovarprice = tovarprice;
        this.magazadress = magazadress;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTovarname() {
        return tovarname;
    }

    public void setTovarname(String tovarname) {
        this.tovarname = tovarname;
    }

    public String getTovarprice() {
        return tovarprice;
    }

    public void setTovarprice(String tovarprice) {
        this.tovarprice = tovarprice;
    }

    public String getMagazadress() {
        return magazadress;
    }

    public void setMagazadress(String magazadress) {
        this.magazadress = magazadress;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

ItemShopClickLIstner

```
public interface ItemShopClickLIstner {
    void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick);
}
```

Метод отправуи

```
private void SaveProductInfoToDatabase() {
        Log.d("Arthur",DownloadImageUrl);
        HashMap<String, Object> OtvetMap = new HashMap<>();
        OtvetMap.put("tovarname", tovarname);
        OtvetMap.put("tovarprice", tovarprice);
        OtvetMap.put("magazadress", magazadress);

OtvetMap.put("image",DownloadImageUrl);
        OtvetMap.put("productId", OtvetRandomKey);
        OtvetMap.put("date", SaveCurrentDate);
        OtvetMap.put("time", SaveCurrentTime);


        otvetRef.child(OtvetRandomKey).updateChildren(OtvetMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(OtvetShopsClientActivity.this, "Ответ отправлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mediaPlayerTwo.start();

                } else {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    String message = task.getException().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(OtvetShopsClientActivity.this, "Ошибка" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        ////сохранение заявки в базе данных конец////


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==GALLERYPICK&&resultCode==RESULT_OK&&data !=null){
            ImageUri=data.getData();
          image_otvet_clientu_photo.setImageURI(ImageUri);
        }

    }

    }
```

Стринги используемые в данном методе

```
private String tovarname,tovarprice,magazadress,SaveCurrentDate,SaveCurrentTime,OtvetRandomKey;
private String DownloadImageUrl;
```

Почему так происходит если все инициализировано?

Comment: значит, инициализировано не все

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: И какая это строка 50 и 53 в Вашем проблемном коде? holder.txt_tovarname - эта?

Comment: Тут же все очевидно, один из ваших txt_* в момент обращения еще не инициализирован. Пишите логи или ставьте точки останова, одним словом учитесь дебажить свой код.