# Jsoup - ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Я пытаюсь получить title сайта с помощью jsoup, но выдаёт `java.lang.NullPointerException`. И именно этот сайт я не могу получить его документ. Другие сайты он нормально получает.

Вот код:

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
    TextView textView;
    public HomeFragment(){
        super(R.layout.fragment_home);
    }
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Button sortButton = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSort);
        Button buttonFilter = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonFilter);
        sortButton.setText("Сортировка");
        buttonFilter.setText("Фильтрация");
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        MyTask mt = new MyTask();
        mt.execute("https://mangalib.me/manga-list?types[]=1");
        

    }
    public void loadMangaImage()
    {

    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(@NonNull String... params) {
            // params - это массив входных параметров
            // в params[0] будет хранится адрес сайта, который мы парсим

            String title= "Error"; // Тут храним значение заголовка сайта

            Document doc = null; // Здесь хранится будет разобранный HTML документ
           

            try {
                // Считываем заглавную страницу
               
                doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Если не получилось считать
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Если всё считалось, что вытаскиваем из считанного HTML документа заголовок
            if (doc != null)
                title = doc.title();
            else
                title = "Error";

            // Передаем в метод onPostExecute считанный заголовок
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            textView.setText(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! Приложите текст и стектрейс ошибки в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1473031/edit).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)