# Затруднение в передаче ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, null

Я пытаюсь реализовать имитацию игры в покер. Создал класс, в котором есть статический метод для создания игральной колоды (уникальность каждой карты реализовал через `Enum` и счетчик).

Для каждой партии игры должна "открыта" новая колода карт. В классе игры я создал `ArrayList` `plaingDeck` и 2 метода: `create()`  и `delete()` соответственно. Но почему-то все элементы списка - `null`.

Код из класса `PlaingDeck`:

```
public static ArrayList<PlaingDeck> createNewPlaingDeck(){
            ArrayList<PlaingDeck> arrayPD = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
                arrayPD.add(new PlaingDeck());
            }
            return arrayPD;
        }
```

Код из класса `Play`:

```
ArrayList<PlaingDeck> plaingDeck;
   
    private void createNewDeck(){
         plaingDeck = PlaingDeck.createNewPlaingDeck();

    }
    private void deleteDeck(){
        plaingDeck.clear();
    }
```

Сама ошибка при компиляции:

> Cannot invoke "java.util.ArrayList.clear()" because "this.plaingDeck" is null

Класс `Play` полностью:

```
public class Play {
    ArrayList<PlaingDeck> plaingDeck;
    Random random = new Random();
    private void createNewDeck(){
         plaingDeck = PlaingDeck.createNewPlaingDeck();

    }
    private void deleteDeck(){
        plaingDeck.clear();
    }
// метод cardDistribution еще не реализован, он ни где не участвует
    private void cardDistribution(Players players){
        for (int i = 0; i < Players.arrayListPlayers.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < players.cardInHand.size(); j++) {
                players.cardInHand.set(j, getRandomCard());
            }
        }
    }
// метод getRandomCard тоже пока не реализован
    private PlaingDeck getRandomCard(){
        return  null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Play play = new Play();
        Players.createPlayers(4);
        play.createNewDeck();
        for (int i = 0; i < play.plaingDeck.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(play.plaingDeck.get(i));
        }
  //      for (Players players: Players.arrayListPlayers) play.cardDistribution(players);
//        for (Players players: Players.arrayListPlayers) players.showCardinHand();
    }
}
```

Comment: "При реализации кода происходит ошибка" - приведите, пожалуйста, эту реализацию.

Comment: Забыл сказать при создание new PlaintDeck, реализовал счетчик в конструкторе, тем самым хочу сказать что при вызове конструктора там создается новая карта по порядку возрастанию и масти. (но не как не null)

Comment: Создаю экземпляр класса Play
Play play = new Play();
play.createNewDeck();
т.е тем самым передаю списку plaingDeck новые значения:
пытаюсь просмотреть содержания списка plaingDeck:

play.createNewDeck();
        for (int i = 0; i < play.plaingDeck.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(play.plaingDeck.get(i));
        }

Comment: Ошибка не в том, что карты в колоде null, а в том, что сама колода - null, то есть, вы её не создаёте. Где вызывается метод createNewDeck()? Вы можете отредактировать вопрос, дополнив его всем кодом из класса Play, а то, как видно, методы в нём закрытые, и поэтому вызывать вы их можете только в рамках данного класса.

Comment: Ошибка, которую вы привели в вопросе, возникает явно при вызове метода `deleteDeck()`. В коде, который вы привели здесь в комментарии, этой ошибки возникнуть не может. Опять же, добавьте в вопрос весь код класса `Play`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Я специально сделал методы в классе Play закрытыми.

Comment: @Fobos1996, в представленном коде ваша проблема не воспроизводится.  Ошибка у вас возникает не при компиляции, а при выполнении кода (runtime) из-за того, что метод `deleteDeck` вызван до инициализации поля `plaingDeck`.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю `plaingDeck` не инициализирована никаким значением перед вызовом метода `deleteDeck()`. Вы пытаетесь очистить список, который равен `null`. Вам нужно инициализировать `plaingDeck` до вызова метода `deleteDeck()`, например, в конструкторе класса Play. Примерно так:

```
public class Play {
    ArrayList<PlaingDeck> plaingDeck = new ArrayList<PlaingDeck>();
    // ...
}
```

Также рекомендую интерфейс `List` вместо конкретной реализации `ArrayList`, чтобы ваш код был более гибким:

```
List<PlaingDeck> plaingDeck = new ArrayList<PlaingDeck>();
```

Или вы создаете `PlaingDeck` в статическом методе `createNewPlaingDeck()`, но не инициализируете их никакими значениями. Это может приводить к тому, что элементы списка равны `null`.

Если это так, то вам нужно инициализировать `PlaingDeck` в цикле for в статическом методе `createNewPlaingDeck()`

```
public static ArrayList<PlaingDeck> createNewPlaingDeck(){
            ArrayList<PlaingDeck> arrayPD = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
                arrayPD.add(new PlaingDeck());
            }
            return arrayPD;
        }
```

Или

```
private void createNewDeck(){
         plaingDeck = new ArrayList<PlaingDeck>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
                plaingDeck.add(new PlaingDeck());
            }
    }
```

Comment: Я к сожалению не совсем вас понял, вы утверждаете что не происходит заполнения списка из-за метода deleteDeck(); я его создал для последующей очистки списка после всех его операций (например раздача карт игрокам и раздача карт на игральный стол) и только после как победитель определен я хотел очищать список-колоду я генерации новой колоды.