# NullPointerException при сохранении imageView в файл

Tags: android, picasso

В манифесте разрешения есть. Картинка с помощью Picasso загружается, но при сохранении всегда пустой файл:

```java
             ImageView ViewPicture  = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            ViewPicture.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            ViewPicture.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Picasso.get()
                    .load("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/vir70_skyview.gif")
                    .into((ImageView) ViewPicture,            new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    //do smth when picture is loaded successfully
                    bitmap=ViewPicture.getDrawingCache();
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "savedBitmapSAVE.png");
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fos = null;
                        try {
                            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                            fos.flush();
                            fos.close();
                        }
                        finally {
                            if (fos != null) fos.close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    };
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    //do smth when there is picture loading error
                             }
            }

);
```

**Ошибка:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Comment: я так понимаю void onSuccess() должна отрабатывать при окончании загрузки картинки, но при сохранении файл все равно пустой сохраняется.  Если вывести процедуру сохранения в отдельную кнопку, файл нормальный создается

Comment: Метод [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) устарел, на последних версиях Android это не работает, используйте [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). Из вопроса не совсем ясно, выполняется ли метод до конца или же пишется ошибка в лог? Приведите логи. И последнее: оставлять пустым `onError` -- это стрелять себе в ногу.

Comment: добрый день. этот код у меня запускается по нажатию кнопки. первый раз выходит ошибка и создается 0 файл, второй раз создается полноценный файл.  Ошибка:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Comment: Метод [`getDrawingCache`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getDrawingCache()) устарел. Кроме этого, в некоторых случаях этот метод возвращает `null`. У вас нет проверки `bitmap` на `null`, поэтому при обращении к `bitmap` у вас возникает [`NullPointerException`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085).