# java.lang.NullPointerException because the return value is null

Tags: java, bukkit

Короче ошибка вот:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.setExecutor(org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor)"
  because the return value of "org.sssumed.mc.claymineeconomy.ClayMineEconomy.getCommand(String)" is null
```

это часть ошибки там дальше там важного нету ничего.

```
paper-plugin.yml:
commands:
  pay:
```

код:

```
this.getCommand("pay").setExecutor((CommandExecutor)new Commands());
```

код2:

```
public class Commands implements CommandExecutor {
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(@NotNull CommandSender commandSender, @NotNull Command command, @NotNull String s, @NotNull String[] strings) {
        commandSender.sendMessage("qwa");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: простите за sendMassege

Comment: `this.getCommand("pay")` у вас возвращает `null` -- в файле конфигурации у вас команда `pay` пустая.

Comment: Я не знаю почему но в plugin yml у меня нету вообще commands. Я смотрел ролики на ютубе в подсказках они были у всех.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Ты же сам ответил, но не сказал как решить проблему. Первый твой комментарий

Comment: И зачем ставить - если на этот вопрос ещё никто не ответил вам нравится просто - ставить? Тута проблема в том что getCommand возвращает null. А плагин yml у меня есть pay

Comment: По сути слили вопрос потому что не могу на него ответить 

Answer (score -1):

Решение очень просто просто не надо писать плагин под paper. На spigot такой же код работает на 100%