# Проблема в том что приходит в блок кода null

Tags: java, null

Вот сам блок кода:

```
public User GetUserById(int id) {
    var users = GetUsers();
    return users.stream().filter(x -> x.id == id).findFirst().get();
}
```

Вот ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "id" because "x" is null

Comment: Если нужны дополнительные детали пишите.

Comment: А что не ясно в написанном?  Давайте логически мыслить....говорит что x null, значит в какой-то момент одно из значений null....А может быть и все...... значит как минимум в users лежит не то, что ожидается.......

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/)

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас действительно выбрасывается исключение `NullPointerException` в представленном коде, значит метод `GetUsers()` возвращает коллекцию, в которой допускаются `null`-овые элементы, что само по себе указывает на плохой дизайн.

Разумеется, можно добавить проверку и отфильтровать `null` значения в стриме, но проблема, повторюсь, в том, что используется метод `GetUsers()`, возвращающий *полную* коллекцию, которая затем фильтруется:

```java
public User GetUserById(int id) {
    return GetUsers().stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(x -> x.id == id)
            .findFirst()
            .get();
}
```

Более стандартное решение состоит в применении *репозитория*, у которого есть *отдельные* методы для получения полной коллекции `findAll` и для получения одного элемента по идентификатору `findById` (в Spring JPA есть также метод `findOne`), тогда код выглядел бы так:

```java
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userRepo.findAll();
}

public User getUserById(int id) {
    return userRepo.findById(id);
}
```